# Data table with pagination feature not working in ajax call?

Tags: ajax, pagination, datatables

I am using data table in my table and I am calling data table functions in ajax call like

```
function readbroadcastedmessagelist()
{
    var usertype = $("#user-type :selected").text();                 
    $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?action=fetchBroadcastedMessageList',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: { usertype: usertype },
                success: function (data) { 
                    $('.filter-table').css("display","block");
                    $('#broadcastedmessagelist').empty();
                    // console.log(data);
                    if (data.length) 
                    {
                        $('#broadcasttable table').dataTable({
                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                        });       
                       for (var i in data) {
                           $("#broadcastedmessagelist").append('<tr>' +
                           '<td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">' +
                           '' + (data[i].userdetails.length ? data[i].userdetails[0]["role"] : ' - ') + 
                           '' + '</td>' + '<td style="text-align: center;">' + '' + 
                           dateSentTextValue + '' + '</td>' + 
                           '<td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible">' + 
                           '<span class="label'+ ' '+ className + '">' + '' + TextValue + 
                           '' + '</td>' + '<td style="text-align: center;">' + 
                           '<button data-id=' + '"'  + data[i]['broadcast_id'] + '"' + 
                           'class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button"' +
                           data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal">' +
                           '<span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button>' +
                           '</td>' +
                           '</tr>');
                       }
                    }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) { }
    });     
}
```

> 1. I am trying to tweak the data table code in order to implement pagination feature only so that rest of the features are omitted.
> 2. It first displays "**No data available in table**" then rest of data in the table.
> 3. pagination is not working properly. Page numbers are not added in table.
> 4. there should be option for showing dropdown for showing records per page.
> 5. It displays "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries" despite there exist data in the table.

The html markup is as

```
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
                                                <thead>
                                                  <tr role="row"><th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                                                    Sender
                                                    </th><th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                                                     Sending Date
                                                    </th><th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;"  rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                                                     Status
                                                    </th><th style="text-align: center; width: 0px;" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                                                     View
                                                    </th></tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody id="broadcastedmessagelist"><tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">07/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="77" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr>
          <tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">07/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="80" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">17/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="81" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr>
                 <tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">17/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="82" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">17/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="83" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr>
              <tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">17/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="84" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">17/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="85" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">17/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="86" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">17/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="87" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center; text-transform:capitalize">admin</td><td style="text-align: center;">17/04/2017</td><td style="text-align: center;" class="footable-visible"><span class="label label-danger">Not Delivered</span></td><td style="text-align: center;"><button data-id="88" class="modalLink btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".myModal"><span class="bold"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</span></button></td></tr></tbody> 
                                            </table>
```

Please help me !!!

Comment: Please show your HTML / markup as well

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Yeah, but meanwhile some @ShahzadMirza totally screwed up the JS part, that edit should never have been approved. Have tried to roll it back.